# Possible to have two between in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to have two between in one query ?

```
 SELECT PH, Chlorine, Temperature, Date, Time FROM googlechart where 
 Date between 2014-03-19 and 2014-03-21 AND
 Time between 15:00 AND 20:00 order by Date, Time;
```

Comment: wouldn't it have been faster and easier to just try instead of posting here?

Comment: yes, it is possible. execute your query and see how it works.

Comment: You do realize that this will pull five hours of data on three days, such as on 2014-03-20, rather than on all the data on that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just forgot the quotes around the date and time

```
SELECT PH, Chlorine, Temperature, Date, Time 
FROM googlechart 
where Date between '2014-03-19' and '2014-03-21'
AND Time between '15:00' AND '20:00' 
order by Date, Time;
```